# Panels with validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a field within the first panel and third panel. When there is an empty field and I click "Next" on panel one, the validation does not display the "please enter first name".  Once I get to the third panel and select "Next", then the validation displays "Please enter name". Is there a way I can have the validation display the notification when there are empty fields based on its specific panel rather than going to the third panel and then seeing the validation?

One aspect I notice: when panel 3 field is not empty, and "Next" is selected, I cant proceed to the fourth panel because the input is empty in panel 1. This occurs vice versa. (if validation displays in panel 1, and then fields are entered, "Next" will not proceed to third panel).

**What I tried**
I tried to target the buttons and remove the class that is targeted by validation. It did not work because validation value is live on all panels 1-4. If I get a thumbs down please inform me on why, so I can improve on my questions next time. Thank you for your time!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $fieldsets =
    $('#panels .sets')
    .first()
    .addClass('active')
    .end()
    .not(':first')
    .hide()
    .end();

  var $panelControlButtons =
    $('#panelcontrol button')
    .filter('.btnPrev')
    .prop('disabled', true)
    .end();


  $('#panelcontrol')
    .on('click', 'button', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      switch (true) {
        case $(this).hasClass('btnNext'):
          var $newFieldset =
            $fieldsets
            .filter('.active')
            .hide()
            .removeClass('active')
            .next()
            .addClass('active')
            .show();

          $('.btnNext').click(function(e) {

            var focusSet = false;
            // validate email - not empty


            //FIRST NAME
            if (!$('#first').val()) {
              if ($("#first").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) {
                $("#first").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-top: -20px;'>Please enter first name</div>");
              }
              //e.preventDefault();

              $('#first').focus();
              focusSet = true;

            } else {
              //ok
              $("#first").parent().next(".validation").remove();
            }


            //after all validate 
            if (focusSet) {

              $("#c").removeClass("btnNext"); //remove class for continue button. Disabling continue
            } else {


              $("#c").addClass('btnNext'); //adds class for the continue button. Enabling continue
            }
            

            //THIRD NAME
            if (!$('#third').val()) {
              if ($("#third").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) {
                $("#third").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-top: -20px;'>Please enter third name</div>");
              }
              //e.preventDefault();

              $('#third').focus();
              focusSet = true;

            } else {
              //ok
              $("#third").parent().next(".validation").remove();
            }


            //after all validate 
            if (focusSet) {

              $("#c").removeClass("btnNext"); //remove class for continue button. Disabling continue
            } else {


              $("#c").addClass('btnNext'); //adds class for the continue button. Enabling continue
            }

          });



          if ($newFieldset.is('.two')) {
            var $newFieldset =
              $fieldsets
              .filter('.active')
              .hide()
              .removeClass('active')
              .next()
              .addClass('active')
              .show();
          }


          //$('.two').removeClass('active'); this removes the second panel when selecting prev button 

          if ($newFieldset.is(':nth-child(2)')) {
            $panelControlButtons
              .next();
          }

          //enable Prev button
          $panelControlButtons
            .filter('.btnPrev')
            .prop('disabled', false);
          $('.btnPrev_one_time').css('display', 'block');



          //disabled Next button
          if ($newFieldset.is(':last-child')) {
            $panelControlButtons
              .filter('.btnNext')
              .prop('disabled', true);
            $(':last-child').find(".btnNext_one_time").text("Place Payment"); //once last child element, btn will change text 
          }


          break; // btnNext
          var $input =
            $('input')
            .filter('.active')
            .end();
        case $(this).hasClass('btnPrev'):
          var $newFieldset =
            $fieldsets
            .filter('.active') //selects the current fieldset
            .hide() //hide it 
            .removeClass('active') //remove active flag
            .prev() //move to the previous fieldset
            .addClass('active') //flag as active
            .show();


          // testing only    $('.two').css('display','none').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active').show().filter();  
          $('.two').css('display', 'none').filter('.active')
            .filter('.active') //selects the current fieldset
            .hide() //hide it 
            .removeClass('active') //remove active flag
            .prev() //move to the previous fieldset
            .addClass('active') //flag as active
            .show();


          //and show it
          // enable Next button
          $panelControlButtons
            .filter('.btnNext')
            .prop('disabled', false);



          // disable Prev button   
          if ($newFieldset.is(':first-child')) {
            $panelControlButtons
              .filter('.btnPrev')
              .prop('disabled', true);
          }
          break; // btn Prev

      }

    }); // panelcontrol button handler


  $('.check_box').on('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $("#second_panel").removeClass('two');
    } else {
      $("#second_panel").addClass('two');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.sets {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="engl">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery/main.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="panels">
      <div class="sets active">
        <h1>PANEL 1</h1><button>Attach/detach paragraphs</button>
        <div>
          <label for="first">First Name</label>
          <input type="first" id="first" placeholder="" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="second_panel" class="sets two">
        <h1>PANEL 2</h1>
        <p>w</p>
        <div>
          <label for="second">Second Name</label>
          <input type="second" id="second" placeholder="" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="sets three">
        <h1>PANEL 3</h1>
        <div>
          <label for="third">Third Name</label>
          <input type="third" id="third" placeholder="" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="sets active">
        <h1>PANEL 4</h1>
        <div><input name="ss4" value="" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form action="">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class="check_box">check for panel 2<br>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="panelcontrol">
    <button class="btnPrev">Prev</button>
    <button class="btnNext" id="c">Next</button>
    <button class="btnNext_one_time">CONTINUE</button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are there so many jQuery scripts in your HTML? 1 should do it.

Comment: Also `switch(true)` doesn't really make sense. Your code is always going to wind up in the `default` block and since you have written a default case, your switch isnt going to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a bit you could do to clean up your code. But if you want to show the validation message as soon as the user does something incorrect then you need your validation function to return as soon as it runs and encounters an issue. Below is an example which shows an error immediately if user doesnt enter and value for first name.

**EDIT:**

```js
var next = document.getElementById('btnNext');
var previous = document.getElementById('btnPrev');
var inputs = [document.getElementById('first'), document.getElementById('second'), document.getElementById('third')];

function init() {
  //show first panel and hide other initially
  document.getElementById('first_panel').className = 'active';
  document.getElementById('second_panel').className = 'sets';
  document.getElementById('third_panel').className = 'sets';
  document.getElementById('fourth_panel').className = 'sets';

  //disable the buttons initially
  previous.disabled = true;
  previous.addEventListener('click', displayPreviousPanel);
  next.disabled = true;
  next.addEventListener('click', displayNextPanel);

  //add keyup event listeners to the text inputs
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      //addEventListener has 'this' bound to current element
      if (validateInput(this.value)) {
        next.disabled = false;
      } else {
        next.disabled = true;
      }
    });
  }
}

function displayPreviousPanel() {
  //should only be 1 active at a time
  var currentlyVisible = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];

  var keyupEvt = new Event('keyup');
  switch (currentlyVisible.id) {
    case 'second_panel':
      document.getElementById('second_panel').className = 'sets';
      document.getElementById('first_panel').className = 'active';
      document.getElementById('first').dispatchEvent(keyupEvt);
      this.disabled = true;
      break;
    case 'third_panel':
      document.getElementById('third_panel').className = 'sets';
      document.getElementById('second_panel').className = 'active';
      document.getElementById('second').dispatchEvent(keyupEvt);
      break;
    case 'fourth_panel':
      document.getElementById('fourth_panel').className = 'sets';
      document.getElementById('third_panel').className = 'active';
      document.getElementById('third').dispatchEvent(keyupEvt);
      break;
  }
}

function displayNextPanel() {
  //disable next button again
  this.disabled = true;

  //undisable previous btn
  previous.disabled = false;

  //should only be 1 active at a time
  var currentlyVisible = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];
  switch (currentlyVisible.id) {
    case 'first_panel':
      document.getElementById('first_panel').className = 'sets';
      document.getElementById('second_panel').className = 'active';
      previous.disabled = false;
      break;
    case 'second_panel':
      document.getElementById('second_panel').className = 'sets';
      document.getElementById('third_panel').className = 'active';
      break;
    case 'third_panel':
      document.getElementById('third_panel').className = 'sets';
      document.getElementById('fourth_panel').className = 'active';
      break;
  }
}

//the function used to validate..add whatever you need here 
function validateInput(value) {
  var isValid = true;
  if (value.length < 1) {
    isValid = false;
  }

  return isValid;
}

init();
```

```css
.sets {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="validationMsg"></div>
  <div id="panels">
    <div id="first_panel" class="sets active">
      <h1>PANEL 1</h1><button>Attach/detach paragraphs</button>
      <div>
        <label for="first">First Name</label>
        <input type="first" id="first" placeholder="" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="second_panel" class="sets two">
      <h1>PANEL 2</h1>
      <p>w</p>
      <div>
        <label for="second">Second Name</label>
        <input type="second" id="second" placeholder="" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="third_panel" class="sets three">
      <h1>PANEL 3</h1>
      <div>
        <label for="third">Third Name</label>
        <input type="third" id="third" placeholder="" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="fourth_panel" class="sets active">
      <h1>PANEL 4</h1>

      <div>
        <label for="second">Fourth Name</label>
        <input name="ss4" value="" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class="check_box">check for panel 2<br>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="panelcontrol">
  <button class="btnPrev" id="btnPrev">Prev</button>
  <button class="btnNext" id="btnNext">Next</button>
  <button class="btnContinue">CONTINUE</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can this work when selecting "Next" for the other panels? What I want to achieve is the following:  the "next" button  cannot be selected in the current panel until the field is entered. When going panel two, "Next " wont work as well until the field is entered.       However, when clicking next in the demo, panel two does not display.  But it should display since an if statement was used for panel 2. Is there an error?  I apologize for inconvenience, and thanks for your time

Comment: @user7293417 I updated the code to reflect what you expressed you wanted in the previous comment. I'm not using any jQuery to do this stuff since I prefer using native javascript where I can. Hope it helps.